# java selenium webdriver - how to output the attribute of a javascript object?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was wondering if anyone could help me find a way to output to the Eclipse console the results returned from executing a Javascript ?

These are the steps I manually perform (that I would like to automate):

1. Open test web page.
2. Open Google chrome Javascript console
3. Type "productObj.mainURL" and enter

This will output to the Chrome Javascript console the URL value/attribute that I'm looking for.

I've done a fair bit of research on my own, and I am stumped.

I've tried the code below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String mainURL = (String) js.executeScript("productObj.mainURL");
System.out.println(mainURL);
```

But all I get returned is a "null"...

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript doesn't return anything, so you get `null` in your `mainURL` string.

Add a `return` statement to the JavaScript:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String mainURL = (String) js.executeScript("return productObj.mainURL;");
System.out.println(mainURL);
```

[Relevant documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html)

Comment: Hey Celeo,

Thanks for the reply.

I've tried the code above and am still getting a null return...

Any other thoughts? Perhaps it's because this javascript object is not being instantiated properly at runtime.. or something like that? -_-

Sorry. Pretty new to all this stuff, so not sure of the proper naming conventions...

Comment: If you think that `productObj` is being loaded/filled/instantiated at a certain time *after* the page finishes loading, you could certainly try to wait for a few seconds before attempting to get it.